# Can we disable Stack Snippets for New Users?

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets, new-users

Runnable code snippets (a.k.a. "Stack Snippets") are a great feature. However, they are also being misused (increasingly frequently, in my experience) by new users, who are using the "JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet" button in the editor toolbar in place of the "Code Sample" button to format their code blocks.

In recent weeks, I would say that, during my reviews of the "Late Answers" and "First Posts" queues, something around 90% of such code snippets posted are *not actually runnable*: sometimes (but rarely) because of minor errors in the code; more often, because they are written in unsupported languages (C and C++ seem quite popular attempts, but maybe I see more of those because I follow the tags).

So, could we limit the use of Stack Snippets™ to users who have crossed a certain threshold? Maybe a very low reputation threshold (like 10, "Remove new user restrictions") or maybe a bit higher? I'm not sure what the restriction is for posting inline images, but using the same for snippets would possibly be about right.

In the meantime, I shall continue to either add a comment on such posts or, if I'm feeling more charitable, edit those posts into *normal* code blocks (and maybe also add a comment).

Comment: I think just [re-arranging the icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkcDy.png) would go a long way. They click the one on the far right and go "Ahh.. so this is where I'm suppose to put my code". Not sure about a reputation restriction though. It would make sense if none of them get it right :)

Comment: Isn't it a lot simpler to remove the html comment wrapper for an inappropriate snippet than to create a new one if user is unable to do it themselves? The latter is typically more tedious.

Comment: @charlietfl It would be a lot simpler if these non-snippets just didn't appear, in the first place. Maybe, for many, it's not a big issue - as you say, editing one or two posts isn't a big deal. However, for those who are active reviewers, 10 - 20 such posts per day becomes rather tiresome.

Comment: Nah... It would be a very odd experience for everyone involved - editors (me included) have consistently been trying to teach new-ish users to *use* the snippets as much as possible (when it comes to HTML, CSS, and JS, of course), so an introduction of a block for new users would likely mostly result in conversations similar to upvoting: "-E: please, use runnable snippets; -OP: what is a snippet? -E: you see this little button? -OP: no...", you get the point. That said, it is *extremely* annoying to see languages that were never supposed to be run - how about stack snippets trying to run...

Comment: ...the code upon insertion into post, and, upon getting a `SyntaxError`, displaying a warning to the user? Not preventing from posting, but displaying an "in your face" notification asking to double-check if the code can be run client-side + pointing to the feature that should be used instead (actually, exactly [or really close to] like the canned comment you posted below)

Comment: FWIW, my current 'canned' comment (maybe should be a bit friendlier): "The code you posted is *not* a runnable snippet (just click the "Run..." button and you will realize that)! Please edit your answer and format your code as a **plain code block** instead (use simple, three back-tick code fences)."

Comment: Can we collect a statistics on how often the feature is misused compared to total uses? (Maybe someone with a good data explorer skill)?

Comment: @BDL Would be nice. But separate stats for new *versus* established users!

Comment: @OlegValter: More like posts which initially had a code snipped that was removed by an edit. Maybe some simple regex on initial state and on current state?

Comment: @AdrianMole ..there's not enough [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TffMr.png) in your canned comment! ;)

Comment: @OlegValter [Here's one I made earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68862084/10871073) (during review).

Comment: @OlegValter: I'm not 100% sure if this is correct, but I think I have a query which returns the posts where a snippet has been removed for a given timeframe: [Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1451636/posts-with-removed-snippets)

Comment: @BDL Well, 99 edits in a week. Not as many as I would have guessed (but the baseline for my estimate is likely biased by being a grumpy reviewer) ... but still rather too many for my liking.

Comment: I don't think disabling them completely is a good idea, but maybe it could show a warning if someone tries to use snippets in a question that's not tagged [html], [css] or [javascript].

Comment: @DonaldDuck Yeah, maybe. I'm actually not too bothered about the downvotes on this question. The point was to get the matter into an informed discussion - which it seems to have achieved, at least.

Comment: @DonaldDuck So.. basically [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410942/can-we-disable-stack-snippets-for-new-users#comment861831_410942) ? :)

Comment: @AdrianMole: Even for the worst case (<= 10rep and question), snippets are used correctly in ~4 out of 5 cases. I don't think disabling the button does the site any favor.

Comment: As to your issue/complaint that HTML/CSS/JS doesn't run in a snippet, because that particular code isn't complete: I would call that a desirable feature. In many cases, being able to know immediately that the HTML/CSS/JS doesn't work as written is significantly beneficial. I've even edited code *into* a snippet just to clearly show the OP that the code doesn't work as written in the question.

Comment: @Makyen Yeah - I *thought* I covered that in my "sometimes (but rarely)..." part. Maybe we should broaden the 'ban' to New Users **and Moderators**? ;-P

Comment: @AdrianMole Perhaps. But, if those first two things are not really your focus (i.e. "sometimes (but rarely) because of minor errors in the code; more often, because they are incomplete HTML or CSS blocks"), then I'd rewrite that sentence to focus on your real concerns (e.g. not place the "written in unsupported languages" as what amounts to an addendum to the other listed issues). Yes, a snippet is often inappropriate for a single line of HTML/CSS/JS, but not *always*. Snippet use/not isn't something I'd want to leave up to an automatic decision which *forces* the user to not use a snippet.

Comment: Prevention of Stack Snippets is definitely a worthy topic of discussion, so I won't downvote this question, even though I *strongly* disagree with its suggested solution of blocking. OTOH, *maybe* some kind of blocking could be appropriate for questions that don't have HTML / JavaScript / CSS tags.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah, fair points. I've removed the "feature-request" tag and just left it as an 'open discussion'.

Answer (score 9):

Statistics on Posts where a snippet has been edited out:

I collected the data for June 2021 (wasn't sure how often the data explorer is updated and to get out the effects of roomba):

*All posts*

|  | Total posts with snippet posted | Posts with snippet removed | % removed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| All user | 10021 | 509 | 5.08% |
| Rep <= 10 | 1009 | 163 | 16.15% |
| Rep > 10 | 9012 | 346 | 3.84% |

*Questions only*

|  | Total posts with snippet posted | Posts with snippet removed | % removed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| All user | 3123 | 366 | 11.72% |
| Rep <= 10 | 756 | 141 | 18.65% |
| Rep > 10 | 2367 | 225 | 9.51% |

[Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1451634/number-of-posts-with-removed-stack-snippet)

Please note that the query is not very stable since it searches (for speed reasons) only for small text parts, but the numbers should be close to what is really going on.

Data for the case where the snippet would be blocked when no web tag is present. So non of [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular), [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), no tag which contains `.js`.

|  | Total posts with snippet posted | Posts with snippet removed | % removed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| All user | 756 | 236 | 31.22% |

The hit rate gets better, but still not great. I guess the tag list would have to be maintained somehow by the community/mods as there will always be new web tags arriving.

I noticed during testing that there are several questions which still contain a snippet, but were it should have been removed, so take the results with a grain of salt.

Comment: SEDE updates each Sunday at 03:00 UTC and is done 6 to 8 hours later.

Comment: So the OP's number of 90% is clearly not accurate, which could be due to selection bias. I'm not sure, but I think some review queues prioritize showing you questions in tags where you're active. Since the OP isn't active in any of [html], [javascript] or [css], this would mean that the OP sees fewer posts where snippets are correctly used than the average.

Comment: Four significant figures are not warranted (e.g. 18.65% for 141/756).

Comment: `Snippet removed` is probably the best possible (searchable) proxy for `snippet improperly applied`; however, the former is always going to under-report.

Comment: The problem with data such as this is that it can only look at those posts which have not been deleted. The poor-question life-cycle results in a substantial percentage of questions being deleted within 9 days after closure and 30 days after posting. Given that what we're interested in here is a quality issue and there will likely be a higher percentage of questions with quality issues deleted, we really can't draw conclusions about the overall population of questions posted from what's available in SEDE when looking for things which correlate with reasons a question/post might be deleted.

Comment: @Makyen: I'm not sure how much that matters for this discussion. A not working snippet is no reason to close a question, so there is something else wrong. If the question should be closed, then there is no need to edit the snipped and thus no work necessary.

Comment: What I see here is we're probably better off blocking snippets in questions where the language tags used suggest snippets don't apply. No clue how complicated that would be.

Comment: @user4581301 likely more complicated than we think :) Although simply analyzing tags and upon determining that the question, say, does not have *any* of the web trio tags, warning the user trying to add one that it does not seem like a question where one should add a runnable snippet and/or suggesting they could edit the post to add the missing tags if they still think the snippet is needed, might be reasonably easy and beneficial to implement

Comment: More complicated than we thought seems to make up, pulling a number out of my ass here, 95% of all software projects.

Comment: @user4581301 true that :) that said, it seems like we all here agree that some sort of static tag analysis and a warning sounds like a good idea that is not very hard to implement. Heck, I can do this with a userscript, and I am not the brightest cookie out there - shouldn't be too much of a problem for SE.

Comment: @OlegValter: See edit. But I noticed that the data is not very reliable since there are tons of posts where the snippet should have been removed but wasn't. The dataset is unfortunately too large to clean it up manually before running the query. Even for a week I would cause major distraction if I'd edit non-runable snippets out.

Comment: @BDL - well, 31% of posts in a week is already a pretty significant number of posts. If we take into account that the pool of editors is quite small, and given there is no guarantee posts that retained snippets should have retained them (as you mentioned), the percentage is likely even higher. This does suggest that there is at least a pulpable issue that could be addressed by warning users that they might be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Other features often misused by new users that we should consider disabling:

- Image upload (often used for text)
- Links (often used for code or images thereof)
- Answers (often used for comments)
- Questions (often poorly written or off-topic)
- Registration (often used to create sockpuppets)

---

More seriously: this seems like a UX problem.  A simple nudge (e.g., "It looks like you're trying to use an JavaScript/HTML/CSS Snippet on a question tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).  Autoconvert to a code block?") would probably go a long way.  Making new users *less* able to create minimal, reproducible examples is not the solution—we already have enough problems getting people to post these.

Comment: How about an editor button that instantly converts a selected Stack Snippet to a plain code block?

Comment: ^ yes, please! Better yet, into up to 3 code blocks with HTML, JS, and CSS separated. Come to think of, this is a nice idea for a userscript in the time it takes SE to do something.

Comment: ^ And does the reverse (combines up to 3 code blocks into a snippet - while we're dreaming of things SE could do for us :)).

Comment: ^ that would be just perfect :) is this editors' rule 34?